# Output sort number in wp menu list item?

Tags: menus, navigation, walker

I want to output the sort number of the list item in it, in the wp menu. No, not by using ordered list `<ol>`.

I have tried search for answers about this by searching on wp forum an reading the documentation. But can't find out how to do.

I guess I will have to use the [walker function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_nav_menu/start_el/) in some way. But how?

**Edit:**
Just for that, I found the answer: `$item->menu_order`

Comment: What do you mean by *sort number*? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

As I edited above, I found the answer myself. Just use: `$item->menu_order`